# zend db sql where with other wheres

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

I want to use some thing likes this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT(other where);
```

Other wheres are like

```
A = 1 AND B = 3
```

Values of A and B are not static. How can I use zend-db to get this query?

```
$where->addPredicate(new PredicateExpression('NOT (?)', (new Where())->equalTo(A = $value));
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me.

`$select->columns(['first_name', 'last_name']);
 $select->from(['U', 'USER']);
 $select->where->equalTo('first_name', 'Larry'); 
 $select->where->expression("NOT(last_name) = 'Harry'", []);`

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't get your question completely, but what i got is you want to put a variable in 'where' inside a query for zend-framework2.

**Take this for example, This query returns all student ids and names WHERE the $id is matched** from table `Students`

```
 $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb->select(array(
                    'PersonalInfo.studentId as studentId',
                    'PersonalInfo.name as studentName',
           ))
                    ->from('Application\Entity\Students', 'PersonalInfo')
                    ->where('PersonalInfo.studentId = :Info')
                    ->setParameter('Info', $id);
                $student = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

> As you can see, in the where portion we have put :info, which is called alias, we give a value to this alias, in the `setParameter`, where you can see a variable `$id`. So `$id` is a random variable which value can be changed. I hope this helps, If you need further instructions, let me know.